# replacing showModalDialog causes loss of form post functionality

Tags: javascript, post, modal-dialog, showmodaldialog

I am replacing the showModalDialog function which no longer works in Chrome and FF. We have many applications using that. The problem is, pop up windows do post instructions to the web server and update the database. For instance if there's a list of accounts on screen and edit is clicked on one of the accounts, an edit page appears as a pop up, posts changes back to the web server, then the list is refreshed with changes. The entire list may be refreshed or just text that changed.

I made a javascript function to do pop up content using overlays. I thought it would be simple to replace showModalDialog calls with the javascript function, but I did not consider post instructions sent by the pop up page to update the database, and complexity to facilitate that. Posting can be done via ajax-like functionality, encapsulated in a set of functions. Before I start writing code to do this I'd like to know what other people have done in this circumstance. Thanks

Comment: `showModalDialog` still works for me on Firefox 37. The console warns it's deprecated, though.

Comment: Firefox is getting rid of it, too. Our users use Chrome or IE, mostly. We could force IE, but then we would not be coding to current standards over all, which wouldn't be good.

Comment: Just curious to know, how easy it was to replace showModalDialog with JS pop-up code? How did you handle the synchronous nature of showModalDialog?

Comment: I posted my code at the URL below. No feedback received, but works excellent for me. The synchronous nature of showModalDialog is done by using translucent overlays to show underlying content, but disable element events. With showModalDialog there are two pages, each with it's own javascript. Without that there is one page. Refreshing the popup via post works as if it was a page, but is handled by a manager. Events such as onload get added to an execute stack. Using modal.js I'm able to fully emulate showModalDialog without much code, and also do more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote some javascript to do everything I want. Since my pop up windows had javascript, I needed to run javascript upon rendering modal content, and also when the modal content went away. This will produce any number of overlays on top of each other, managing each. Content can optionally appear in a frame with a title bar, closely matching the functionality of showModalDialog.

Download at http://bikehappy.org/modal.html . If used, please give feedback saying if it works and provide update suggestions.